# Solving $ mx'' = -mg - k_1 x' + k_2 (x')^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

When trying to solve the tipical problem of free fall of an object with air drag we arrive at the differential equation:

$$ mx'' = -mg - k_1 x'  +  k_2 (x')^2 $$

with initial conditions: $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=0$, where $x=x(t)$.

By trying $\beta = (x')^2$ and re writting $x''= \frac{1}{2} (\frac{d}{dt} x'^2)$ I arrived at:

$$ \frac{1}{2}m \beta' = -mg - k_1 \sqrt{\beta}  +  k_2 \beta $$

It looks like a Ricatti equation but with the square root there. How do I manage this?

Comment: Note that the last term should be $k_2|x'|x'$ to be a friction term. The operations should also be subtractions, friction always slows down. // Keywords "separable" and "Riccati DE".

Comment: Are you sure you want LHS to be $x''$ not $mx''$?  Note that $x''=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[\frac12 x'^2]$ may come in handy.

Comment: I considered the axis to be pointing up so the gravitational force would have a negative sign and the drag forces would have a positive one

Comment: So the motion is falling down, $x'$ is negative. Then friction force should be positive, pointing up. This works with the last term, but not the middle one.

Comment: I edited the question. I still dont know how  to solve it even tho it almost looks like a Riccati equation

Comment: Let $x' = u$ and solve the first-order ODE...

$$u' + \frac{k_{1}}{m}u - \frac{k_{2}}{m}u^{2} = -g.$$

This is a Riccati equation.

Comment: I really think @user10354138 means what he says that $x''=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}[\frac12 x'^2]$ and not $x''=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[\frac12 x'^2]$.